# Python nlp: Creating flags (new column with 0 and 1) based on the top word frequencies

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas, nlp, text-mining

I have a df with a text column (~500 rows and each line is a short description which contains details of cars and service that was done for each customer). I use the code below to find the word frequencies. I want to create a new column with 0 and 1 (based on the top tokens displayed as below).

For e.g. if the text contains 'part1' (50 times), then there will be 50 rows with 1's as flags.

**Data Sample:**

```
print(df['txt'].head().to_dict())

{0: 'HONDA WIPER FLUID REFILL',
1: 'KIA TIRE ROTATION AND OIL CHANGE', 
2: 'KIA OIL AND FILTER CHANGE'}
```

**Frequency Counts:**

```
WordCounter = Counter()
for text in doc_list:
  words = text.split(' ')
  for word in words:
    WordCounter[word]+=1
    
print(WordCounter.most_common(30))

[('KIA', 100), ('OIL', 50), ('FILTER', 25)....]
```

And I know I can use the below code to do it manually by giving the keywords in str.contains('XXX').

```
df['flag'] = np.where(df['txt'].str.contains("part1|part2", case=False, na=False), '1', '0')
```

But there will be new data that might be coming in and I want to just use the top 5-10 most frequent keywords from wordcounter and automatically tag those occurrences.

Comment: Can you update your post with a sample of your dataframe, please? `print(df['txt'].head().to_dict())`

Comment: @Corralien Updated with sample data

Comment: @Corralien Another approach could be regexes, but that again does require developing for each keyword

Comment: Ok it's better now.